# Time Comparison in angular js

Tags: angularjs, time, ionic-framework

I want to compare two datetime objects. But `alert $scope.timeDiff` is showing `NaN` undefined.

Code:

```
$scope.dbDealTime =  $filter('date')(data.DealTime, 'hh:mm:ss'); 
$scope.TimeNow =  $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss');

$scope.timeDiff = $scope.dbDealTime - $scope.TimeNow;
alert($scope.timeDiff);
```

Comment: You need check if data.DealTime is defined or undefined.

Comment: oh yeah. it was undefined but now it is defined but the difference is now NaN in alert.

Comment: use this $filter('date')(new Date(data.DealTime), 'MMM dd yyyy');

Comment: @VishalSharma i want time difference what you suggest looks like date difference.

Comment: you can get the time like this $filter('date')(new Date(data.DealTime), 'HH:mm:ss');

Comment: alert the data.DealTime and tell me what you are getting ?

Comment: Mon Feb 15 2016 18:56:48 GMT 0500 (PKT)

Comment: first do subtraction then add filter to it, `data.DealTime - new Date()` then add filter to its subtraction

Comment: Thanks man. this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.timeDiff = data.DealTime - new Date();
```

Then apply filter to it

```
$filter('date')($scope.timeDiff, 'hh:mm:ss');
```

Then show whatever you want in alert

```
alert($scope.timeDiff);
```